# Running an external application in Backgroundworker as an administrator in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am working on a project in C# in **Visual Studio 2012**

I am running an external exe in backgroundworker, but the external exe is creating a text file in c:\programdata which requires Administrator privileges.

the query i have is whether running my project as administrator will assign administrator privileges to the external exe or not? or how should i address this issue. kindly guide me

Comment: ProgramData doesn't require administrative privileges, in fact it exists specifically for apps to write to without them.

Comment: By assuming that you do need admin privileges to open a given file, what is exactly your question? How to make the .exe generated by your C# solution to have admin privileges?

Comment: No i want to ask if i assign administrator privileges to my c# solution, then the thread which this solution is created would have administrator privileges or not?

Comment: @TheCodeKing I have checked programdata requires administrator privileges

Comment: If you assign admin privileges to the .exe generated by your solution, it would be able to perform any action requiring admin-privileges.

Comment: @WiXXeY actually yes you may be right. I think users can read but not write. `ProgramData` can be written to without elevation by an installer.